# Convert sql temp table syntax to linq syntax

Tags: sql, linq, temp-tables

Can anyone convert this SQL syntax to Linq syntax which generates a temp table.

```
SELECT TOP 400 N=IDENTITY(INT, 0, 1)--int0,1
Into #tmpNumbers
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;
```

Comment: There are much better ways to generate the result than that...

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not have a way to create a temp table on the fly. There is no direct conversion of your SQL to LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't using `a` or `b` in your `SELECT`, their only purpose is a complicated way to generate a count. Just do this:

```
var rowcount = master.dbo.syscolumns.Count();
var tmpNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(rowcount*rowcount, 400));
```